# PoE: Can I use the TL-POE150S injector with the Unifi AP?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

My PoE (Power over Ethernet) **injector** is a TP-Link [TL-POE150S](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-4794_TL-POE150S.html) that, according to the [specifications](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-4794_TL-POE150S.html#specifications), is supposed to perform **auto-sensing** for the needed power of the remote powered device at `15.4W (Max. 48VDC)`.

My **Access Point** is a PoE capable [Ubiquiti UniFi AP](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap/) that, according to the [specifications](https://www.ubnt.com/downloads/datasheets/unifi/UniFi_AP_DS.pdf) requires a **24 VDC** power coming via ethernet cable: `24V, 0.5A PoE Adapter Included`.

Both devices seem to be **802.3af** compliant.
So, **can I use** this PoE 802.3af injector **with** this PoE 802.3af capable device?

Answer (score 0):

<del>In short: I don't know the technical reason, but **you can not**.</del>

<del>I think many things are not still clear about PoE.

I have **tested** a TL-POE150S with a UniFi AP, and the Ubiquiti device started **blinking and failing** (I was not able to connect to the WiFi network) after a few minutes.

I then changed and put its own (included) injector, and everything went fine (I have the device working 24 hours a day).</del>

<del>So, I assume the auto-sensing capability of the injector does not apply to Voltage, and keeps sending 48 VDC, not 24 VDC as the device requires. That is a bad thing when talking about electronics.</del>

Like most [Ubiquiti devices](https://www.ubnt.com/accessories/poe-adapters/) as for today (February 2016), they are PoE but **not 802.3af** (nor 802.3at) compliant (as so, you will not find such words on its docs), but rather **Passive PoE**.
This is: the device will start (boot) if you send the *correct voltage* via ethernet cable but will have **no voltage negotiation** capabilities.

In this case, your TL-POE150S is sending 48 Volts to the UniFi AP, that according to its [specifications](https://www.ubnt.com/downloads/datasheets/unifi/UniFi_AP_DS.pdf) works with `Passive Power over Ethernet (12-24V)`.

Sending 48 Volts (twice the proper voltage) will make the device to become hot, hang, and even become damaged as time goes by.